Split an email in a query
I have a Table called user which contain a field name and an email
Email all follow this syntax
name.forname@domain.com
And I want to have a query that update my name table so it looks like this
name forname
I already tried to use string_split.
How to split an email address into its parts
I used this ref to understand but the SELECT throw me an error.
The thing is I don't understand how to use it.
If someone could just explain how it works it would be great.

Don't use string_split. Instead use SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX. What error did you get when you tried to use the examples in the link?

String_Split splits a column into rows. You can try substing/charindex, or maybe parsename.

Please try the following solution based on the PARSENAME() function.
So, we will use tokenization method instead of strings parsing.
Assumption is that all emails are strictly following identical four part format as name.forname@domain.com
SQL
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(50), email VARCHAR(128));
INSERT @tbl (name, email) VALUES
('name1', 'name.forname@domain.com'),
('name2', 'john.doe@yahoo.com');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

-- before
SELECT * FROM @tbl;

UPDATE t1
SET name = PARSENAME(tokens, 4) + SPACE(1) + PARSENAME(tokens, 3)
FROM @tbl AS t1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT REPLACE(email,'@', '.')) AS t2(tokens);

-- after
SELECT * FROM @tbl;

Output



id
name
email




1
name forname
name.forname@domain.com


2
john doe
john.doe@yahoo.com




How to apply your example to this link How to split an email address into its parts
Your error may be due to the use of user as a table name. USER is a reserved word so you must use brackets with it.
SELECT 
LEFT(email, CHARINDEX('@', email) - 1) AS accountName  
,LEFT(LEFT(email, CHARINDEX('@', email) - 1) , CHARINDEX('.', email) - 1)  As [Name before period]   
,RIGHT(LEFT(email, CHARINDEX('@', email) - 1) , LEN(LEFT(email, CHARINDEX('@', email) - 1)) - CHARINDEX('.', LEFT(email, CHARINDEX('@', email) - 1)))    As [Name after period] 
,RIGHT(email, LEN(email) - CHARINDEX('@', email)) AS domainWithExtension
,LEFT(RIGHT(email, LEN(email) - CHARINDEX('@', email)), CHARINDEX('.', RIGHT(email, LEN(email) - CHARINDEX('@', email))) - 1) AS domain
,RIGHT(RIGHT(email, LEN(email) - CHARINDEX('@', email)), LEN(RIGHT(email, LEN(email) - CHARINDEX('@', email))) - CHARINDEX('.', RIGHT(email, LEN(email) - CHARINDEX('@', email)))) AS extension
FROM [user]

so from this we can construct an update:
UPDATE [user] 
SET name=
LEFT(LEFT(email, CHARINDEX('@', email) - 1) , CHARINDEX('.', email) - 1)  
+ ' ' + 
RIGHT(LEFT(email, CHARINDEX('@', email) - 1) , LEN(LEFT(email, CHARINDEX('@', email) - 1)) - CHARINDEX('.', LEFT(email, CHARINDEX('@', email) - 1))) 

fiddle



accountName
Name before period
Name after period
domainWithExtension
domain
extension




name.forname
name
forname
domain.com
domain
com


name1.forname1
name1
forname1
domain1.com
domain1
com


name2.forname2
name2
forname2
domain1.com
domain1
com


name3.forname3
name3
forname3
domain1.com
domain1
com


name4.forname4
name4
forname4
domain1.com
domain1
com




If I get your question right, which is to update you name column with the names included in the Email column, you can try this query:
UPDATE [user]
SET name = SUBSTRING(email, 1, CHARINDEX('.', email) - 1) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(email, CHARINDEX('.', email) + 2, CHARINDEX('@', email) - CHARINDEX('.', email) - 2)
WHERE CHARINDEX('.', email) > 0;

this basically does a concatenation of two substrings (with a space ' ' in between) and affect them to the name attribute for each row in your User table, using beforehand know separators (the '.' and .'@').
the WHERE clause here is just to garantee that the query takes effect only on the rows whose email values contain the '.' char.

Thanks for the information, i tried and got this error
Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
